# Which of these two statements is true?

Tags: real-analysis

1. $\inf_A (cf+g) \le c \inf_A f + \inf_A g$ for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $\inf_A (cf+g) \ge c \inf_A f + \inf_A g$ for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that: $\inf_A(cf+g) \ge \inf_A(cf)+\inf_A(g) $, but then it seems like I'd have to assume $c>0, c<0$. However the statements say "for all $c$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither answer is correct when no additional info is given for the sign of $c$.

1) is incorrect for example for $f(x)=\sin(x), g(x)=-\sin(x), c=1, A=\mathbb R$, as $cf+g\equiv 0$ and $\inf_Af=\inf_Ag=-1$.

2) is incorrect for example for $f(x)=\sin(x)-2, g(x)=0, c=-1, A=\mathbb R$, as $\inf_Af=-3, \sup_Af=-1$ and thus $\inf_A{-f}=1, -\inf_A{f}=3$.

Answer (score 0):

$c \in \mathbb{R}.$

$\inf_A (cf)  \le (cf)(a),$ $a \in A$ ;

$\inf_A(g) \le g(a)$, $a \in A$:

$\inf_A (cf) +\inf_A(g) \le (cf+g)(a),$ $a \in A.$

$\inf_A(cf) +\inf_A(g)$ is a lower bound of $(cf+g)(a)$, $a \in A.$

By definition $\inf_A(cf+g)$ is the greatest lower bound for $(cf+g)(a)$, $a \in A$.

Hence

$\inf_A(cf) + \inf_A(g) \le \inf_A(cf +g)$.

1) Let $c \gt 0$, and $f \ge 0$.

Then $\inf_A (cf)= c\inf_A (f)$ √.

2) $c \gt 0$, and $f \lt 0$, for some $a \in A$.

Then $\inf_A (cf) =c \inf_A(f) $√.

3) $c \lt 0$ . See counterexample by Ingix.